# GitHub Pages: README.md in docs folder

Tags: github

I set my Github Pages source to `myRepo/docs`.

In `/docs` there is a friendly `README.md` and an `index.html` which is part of the `scaladoc`.

I want `README.md` to be the landing page but currently the default is `index.html`.

Can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way github pages work by default is by looking for index.html, if it's not there it goes to README.md.

You need to delete index.html from `gh-pages` branch and only keep README.md there

Comment: OK, thanks, I will re-organize with my scaladoc in a sub directory.